# How to compute sum with large intermediate values

Tags: python, math

I would like to compute

[image: S = n + m - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}]

for *n* ≥ *m* with both values being integers ranging up to 1000. The end result is a number not much bigger than *n* but the intermediate values are much too large for python to cope with. How can you solve this?

I define the function as follows.

```
from scipy.misc import comb
def S(n,m):
    return n+m-sum([k**(k - 1)*comb(n, k)*(n - k)**(n + m - k)/n**(n + m - 1) for k in xrange(1,n+1)])
```

The error I get for `n=m=100`, for example, is

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  return n+m-sum([k**(k - 1)*comb(n, k)*(n - k)**(n + m - k)/n**(n + m - 1) for k in xrange(1,n+1)])
[...]
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Comment: Sorry, LaTeX doesn't work on SO (although I wish it did.  I really, really do.)  Want to reformat that question so it reads a little better?

Comment: Too large integers for Python to cope with? Are you sure?

Comment: Python can handle integers of arbitrary size. Do you mean numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by "values are much too large for python to cope with"? How do you compute the sum? What's the result? What result did you expect?

Comment: For which values of `n` and `m`? How is  `comb` defined?

Comment: Added more detail which hopefully answers all the questions so far.

Comment: Thank you! I think all the information is now in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the problem is in scipy's [`comb`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html) definition. When I supply a homemade version, it works fine:

```
import math

def choose(n,k):
    return math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(k)*math.factorial(n-k))

comb = choose

def S(n,m):
    return n+m-sum([k**(k - 1)*comb(n, k)*(n - k)**(n + m - k)/n**(n + m - 1) for k in xrange(1,n+1)])

print S(1000,1000)
```

result (in about 1.5 seconds):

```
1844
```

As an alternative to writing your own `comb`, try passing `True` in for the optional `exact` argument to `comb`. Seems like you'll get a float back otherwise, which may mess things up.

Comment: Not only does adding exact=True fix the problem, it also speeds it up hugely!  I can then add from __future__ import division and it still works. That looks a bit like a bug in comb to me.

Comment: I will do but.. I think it's polite to leave a question open for at least an hour for those who don't type as quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.misc.comb` returns an `ndarray` of one floating point number in this case. The rest of your computations are done with integers (eventually long integers in Python < 3). When multiplying a floating point number by an int, Python tries to convert it to a float, but 99**199 ~ 1e397 doesn't fit in a Python float (64 bits), so it raises an error.

A solution is to pass `exact=True` as an argument to `comb`. By the way, you can remove `[` and `]` inside `sum`: this avoids the creation of the inner list, so it should be faster and more memory efficient (it's similar to the difference between `range` and `xrange`). And if you ever happen to be adding up floating point numbers (not needed here), it's much better to use `math.fsum` (accurate floating point sum of values) than `sum`.