# Compute sum with huge intermediate values

Tags: python, math

I would like to compute

[image]

for values of `n` up to `1000000` as accurately as possible. Here is some sample code.

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.misc import comb
def M(n):
    return sum(comb(n,k,exact=True)*(1/n)*(1-k/n)**(2*n-k)*(k/n)**(k-1) for k in xrange(1,n+1))
for i in xrange(1,1000000,100):
    print i,M(i)
```

The first problem is that I get `OverflowError: long int too large to convert` to float when `n = 1101`.  This is because `comb(n,k,exact=True)` is too large to be converted to a float.  The end result is however always a number around `0.159` .

I asked a related question at [How to compute sum with large intermediate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044801/how-to-compute-sum-with-large-intermediate-values) however this question is different for three main reasons.

1. The formula I want to compute is different which causes different problems.
2. The solution proposed before to use exact=True does not help here as can be seen in the example I gave. Coding up my own implementation of comb is also not going to work as I still need to perform the floating point division.
3. I need to compute the answer for much bigger values than before which causes new problems. I suspect it can't be done without coding up the sum in some clever way.

A solution that doesn't crash is to use

```
from fractions import Fraction
def M2(n):
    return sum(comb(n,k,exact=True)*Fraction(1,n)*(1-Fraction(k,n))**(2*n-k)*Fraction(k,n)**(k-1) for k in xrange(1,n+1))
for i in xrange(1,1000000,100):
    print i, M2(i)*1.0
```

Unfortunately it is now so slow that I don't get an answer for `n=1101` in a reasonable amount of time.

So the second problem is how to make it fast enough to complete for large `n`.

Comment: The question was asked yesterday!!!!

Comment: @0x90 It was a different (but related) question yesterday. Most importantly the solution from yesterday doesn't help for this problem.

Comment: Looks like the exact same problem to me, even if you change the wording of the question a bit.

Comment: @Wooble The formula is different and the solution doesn't work. Using exact=True doesn't help here.

Comment: `exact = True` might not work, but using your own `comb()` function that uses native Python integers instead of C `long`s should work the same, since the problem is integer overflow and Python `int` are arbitrary precision.

Comment: @Wooble I got that to work using fractions. However it causes the second problem.

Comment: Fair enough; voted to re-open. But the title should possibly be changed to reflect that you're looking to do real division on huge integers, not summing huge integers.

Comment: @Wooble Thanks. One possible solution may be to find a way to perform the sum without ever creating these huge values in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute each summand in with a logarithm transformation that replaces multiplication, division, and exponentiation with addition, subtraction, and multiplication, respectively.

```
def summand(n,k):
    lk=log(k)
    ln=log(n)
    a=(lk-ln)*(k-1)
    b=(log(n-k)-ln)*(2*n-k)
    c=-ln
    d=sum(log(x) for x in xrange(n-k+1,n+1))-sum(log(x) for x in xrange(1,k+1))
    return exp(a+b+c+d)

def M(n):
    return sum(summand(n,k) for k in xrange(1,n))
```

Note that when k=n the summand will be zero so I do not compute it since the logarithm will be undefined.

Comment: That gets me up to 10001 fairly easily. Thanks!  Maybe I should combine yours with gmpy2 as well. (I think M(n) needs a "return" added.)

Comment: Does this come with a loss of precision? You have `M(2001) == 0.1585749003811831`, while @casevh has `0.15857490038127975` which matches my result (except for the last digit). (Or is yours more exact? I don't know.)

Comment: @WolframH I would expect it to lose precision as it only gives approximations for n choose k where some of the other methods compute it exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/). It has arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic with large exponent bounds.

```
from __future__ import division
from gmpy2 import comb,mpfr,fsum

def M(n):
    return fsum(comb(n,k)*(mpfr(1)/n)*(mpfr(1)-mpfr(k)/n)**(mpfr(2)*n-k)*(mpfr(k)/n)**(k-1) for k in xrange(1,n+1))
for i in xrange(1,1000000,100):
    print i,M(i)
```

Here is an excerpt of the output:

2001 0.15857490038127975
2101 0.15857582611615381
2201 0.15857666768820194
2301 0.15857743607577454
2401 0.15857814042739268
2501 0.15857878842787806
2601 0.15857938657957615

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Answer (score 2):

A rather brutal method is to compute all the factors and then mutliply in such a way that the result stays around 1.0 (Python 3.x):

```
def M(n):
    return sum(summand(n, k) for k in range(1, n + 1))

def f1(n, k):
    for i in range(k - 1):
        yield k
    for i in range(k):
        yield n - i

def f2(n, k):
    for i in range(k - 1):
        yield 1 / n
    for i in range(2 * n - k):
        yield 1 - k / n
    yield 1 / n
    for i in range(2, k + 1):
        yield 1 / i

def summand(n, k):
    result = 1.0
    factors1 = f1(n, k)
    factors2 = f2(n, k)
    while True:
        empty1 = False
        for factor in factors1:
            result *= factor
            if result > 1:
                break
        else:
            empty1 = True
        for factor in factors2:
            result *= factor
            if result < 1:
                break
        else:
            if empty1:
                break
    return result
```

For `M(1101)` I get `0.15855899364641846`, but it takes a few seconds. `M(2000)` takes about 14 seconds and yields `0.15857489065619598`.

(I'm sure it can be optimised.)

Comment: I think those answers are wrong. For n=1101 it should be 0.158559 to six decimal places.

Comment: Also I believe the function is strictly increasing but you get a smaller value for M(2000) than M(1000).

Comment: @Anush: I also get `M(4) < M(3)`, so something must be wrong. Can you tell me the correct values for `M(3)` and `M(4)`, so I can find out if it is an accuracy issue, or if I missed some factors?

Comment: (1 0.0), (2 0.125), (3 0.139917695473), (4 0.145751953125), (5 0.148867072)   . Also the function `M' in the question gives answers for values up to around 1000.